# Is there any way to implement the mathematical deconvolution(which exactly reverse the convolution) using tensorflow? Please let me know if there is

Tags: tensorflow, deconvolution

I'm trying to make a software in which I need to reverse the convolution process. I haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called Transposed Convolution in Tensorflow and also in PyTorch. Here is the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose) for TF1.14.
[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose) is for TF2.0.

Comment: It will not give us the original layer which was before convolution. Transposed Convolution will not exactly reserve the convolution operation.